# Angular : Select box getting cleared on form submit

Tags: javascript, angularjs

on form submit if error occurs don't clear selected value from drop down list

**Here is the angular controller code**

```
$scope.registerTutorSubmint = function(form, button) {
        $("#gifLoading").removeClass().addClass('show');
        $scope.registerTutor.registrationTime = new Date();
        $scope.registerTutor.country_id = $scope.registerTutor.country_id.id;
        $scope.registerTutor.countryCode_id = $scope.registerTutor.countryCode_id.id;
        $scope.registerTutor.timeZone = $scope.registerTutor.timeZone.cityTimezone;
          if (!$scope.$$phase)
              $scope.$apply();
        tutorOperations.registerTutor($scope.registerTutor)
            .then(function(response) {
                if(response.data.message=='ER_DUP_ENTRY'){
                      alertService.showAlert("Register Tutor","Duplicate Email Entry");
                }else if(response.data.statuscode == 200){
                    alertService.showAlert("Register Tutor",response.data.message=="success"?"New Tutor Added Successfully":response.data.message)
                    .then(function(response){
                        if(response==='ok'){
                            $scope.registerTutor = {};
                            form.$setPristine();
                            form.$setUntouched();
                            button == 'addOneMore' ? '' : $location.path(Routes.manageTutor.url);
                        }

                    });
                 }
                $("#gifLoading").removeClass().addClass('hide');

            });
    };
```

When I get the response, drop down is getting cleared. So what should I do to make sure that drop down select value is not cleared.

Comment: Add html of your dropdown and create a plunker if you can. We really need more precise informations to help you. And show code of tutorOperations.registerTutor

Comment: Thanks for reply @LG_ 1 hour ago i got the solution i was modifying the main object "$scope.registerTutor" instead i used angular.copy($scope.registerTutor) and the issue solved